# How to speed up directory listing on high-inode partitions?

Tags: inode

I have almost 7,000 files in a single directory which makes loading that particular directory a tedious and time-consuming one. Is there any way to list and perform operations on files in that directory faster rather than distributing the files into multiple sub-folders(which makes it even more difficult)?

I'm using ext4. But also received the same from efs filesystems.

Comment: It's better to you make filter, you have some way, find, globbing and so on , But at first you explain exactly your task.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "loading"? Simply `ls`, or displaying the contents in a file manager (which one?), or something else? On my system listing 7,000 files with `ls` on an `ext4` filesystem is pretty much instantaneous, as is displaying the directory in Thunar.

Comment: @SnazzySanoj please answer comments, by amending your question.

Comment: A lot of systems alias `ls` to something that makes it `lstat` every file. --color and -F do this. If you don't need `ls` to decorate the output, remove these aliases. Listing a 7000 file directory shouldn't be slow.

Answer (score 1):

A large directory can be problematic for a number of reasons other than simply listing of files.  For one thing, the time it takes to open a file in that directory will increase because the directory has to be read until the file is found.  On many filesystems including ext*, directory entries not organized nor optimized for retrieval efficiency.

Answering your specific question, I think that you'll find using ls takes awhile due to the sorting involved.  A solution is to run ls unsorted (if there is such an option in your distribution of ls).  Specifically, I might ls unsorted to a file and the sort it.  I then have the file to refer to without having to do another ls for a bit.

Another similar method is to use the find command and listout the directory contents into a file (which will be unsorted) and then go from there.

Thus my suggestion would be based on accessibility, effeciency and easily finding files, to use multiple sub-directories.

Comment: "**A directory is not organized to speed up retrievals of specific entries**": that completely depends on the filesystem in use, and many commonly-used filesystem types *do* optimize directory indices for just this ability.

Comment: OK, I qualified my response.  Could you provide the commonly used filesystems that do what you state for the record?

Comment: [XFS](http://xfs.org/docs/xfsdocs-xml-dev/XFS_Filesystem_Structure/tmp/en-US/html/Btree_Directories.html) automatically, ext4 (probably ext3 as well?) with the "dir_index" option enabled (which is part of the default options) (see mkfs.ext4 manpage), and I didn't bother to look up references but probably most of the other modern filesystem types as well: Btrfs, ZFS, JFS, all support efficient indexing for large directories.